# Account.MasterRecordId does not belong to SObject type Account

Tags: apex, trigger, account, merge, sobjectexception

I constantly get an System.SOBjectException during execution of `afterDelete` trigger for **Account** object. This exception is raised when the `SObjectUtils.getIdsFromField` is invoked. I've just run the `SObjectUtils.getIdsFromField` directly from the Developer Console to check if the problem is related to this method, but it seems to be okay.

**Exception**:

```
caused by: System.SObjectException: Account.MasterRecordId does not belong to SObject type Account
```

**Account Trigger Handler code**:

```
public inherited sharing class AccountTrigHand extends TriggerHandler {

    private final List<Account> newRecords;
    private final Map<Id, Account> oldRecordById;
    public AccountTrigHand() {
        this.newRecords = (List<Account>) Trigger.new;
        this.oldRecordById = (Map<Id, Account>) Trigger.oldMap;
    }

    public override void afterDelete() {

        Set<Id> masterRecordIds = SObjectUtils.getIdsFromField(
                Account.MasterRecordId,
                this.oldRecordById.values()
        );
```

**SObjectUtils.getIdsFromField:**

```
    public static Set<Id> getIdsFromField(Schema.SObjectField field, List<SObject> records) {
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
        for (SObject record : records) {
            Id value = (Id) record.get(field);
            if (value != null) {
                ids.add(value);
            }
        }
        return ids;
    }
```

Comment: What line is throwing this error? It seems hard to believe any of this code could throw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I only get this error when merging Person Accounts using Account Merge Wizard in Classic. If I had to guess, it seems that Apex Engine has some problems in parsing `Account.MasterRecordId` token for Person Accounts, but only in old / legacy tools like Account Merge Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug where at runtime, the apex engine is not able to parse out the correct field name string from the `Schema.SObjectField`. You might want to log a support ticket with Salesforce for this.

I would try something like below as an alternative approach

```
public static Set<Id> getIdsFromField(String field, List<SObject> records) {
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    for (SObject record : records) {
        Id value = (Id) record.get(field);
        if (value != null) {
            ids.add(value);
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

__

```
public inherited sharing class AccountTrigHand extends TriggerHandler {

private final List<Account> newRecords;
private final Map<Id, Account> oldRecordById;
public AccountTrigHand() {
    this.newRecords = (List<Account>) Trigger.new;
    this.oldRecordById = (Map<Id, Account>) Trigger.oldMap;
}

 public override void afterDelete() {

    Set<Id> masterRecordIds = SObjectUtils.getIdsFromField(
            'MasterRecordId',
            this.oldRecordById.values()
    );
```

For Additional safety you might want to inspect those IDs and make sure they belong to objects that can be merged like below

```
for (SObject record : records) {
        if(record instanceof Account || record instanceof Contact || record instanceof Lead) {
         Id value = (Id) record.get(field);
         if (value != null) {
            ids.add(value);
         }
       }
    }
    return ids;
```